# PHP upload_max_filesize doesn't change

Tags: php, ini, upload-max-filesize

I'm trying to change the php config for **upload_max_filesize** on my server (LEMP Stack).

In phpinfo I can see:

```
Loaded Configuration File:  /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
```

I've changed upload_max_filesize to 256M in this file.

Then I've restarted by running this command: `systemctl restart nginx`.

The problem is that when I check my phpinfo it hasn't changed... .

Comment: Have you tried to restart php-fpm service as well? `systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to restart the php-fpm service for the changes to take effect:

```
systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service
```